# Cassandra keyspace JMX metrics TotalDiskUsage - Is it calculated for node or cluster?

Tags: cassandra, jmx, metrics

I'm connecting to Cassandra with JMX (host:port) and querying with the ObjectName:

"org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Keyspace,keyspace=keySpaceName,name=TotalDiskSpaceUsed"

Then I fetch the Attribute "Value" which I suppose is the total disk usage in bytes for the keyspace (in my example, which is small, returns 10516).

In my test I only have a one-node-cluster, but what if I have a cluster of hundreds of nodes with a lot of tables with different partition keys, will the value then be for the whole cluster or is it just the value for the node I connect to?

Answer (score 1):

All JMX metrics, including TotalDiskUsage, are measurements for the local node only.